# Sending transformation to vertex shader fails

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader, opengl-3

I'm doing my first steps with OpenGL and currently fail to send some transformations to my vertex shader. When I use following shader program, everything works fine and I can see my object (a simple triangle):

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

In next step I changed the shader program to accept transformations from outside:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
uniform mat4 inputTransform;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = inputTransform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

...and my main loop to send transformation data to the shader:

```
unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"inputTransform");
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
GLfloat trans[4] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE,trans);
```

Now my triangle disapperas as some very invalid transformation would have been applied. Value in "shaderProgram" is correct, it works properly with a prior call to the fragment shader. I also do not get any compilation errors for the shader programs.

So any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uniform `mat4 inputTransform` is a 4*4 matrix and not a vector with 4 components.
See [Data Type (GLSL) - Matrices](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Matrices)

You have to initialize it with an array of 16 floats, e.g. by an [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix):

```
GLfloat trans[16] = {
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
};
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, trans);
```

---

The matrix contains the translation, orientation (and scale). In GLSL a `mat4` can be initialized:

```
mat4 m44 = mat4(
    vec4( Xx, Xy, Xz, 0.0),
    vec4( Yx, Xy, Yz, 0.0),
    vec4( Zx  Zy  Zz, 0.0),
    vec4( Tx, Ty, Tz, 1.0) );
```

This means, if you want to init the matrix with an translation vector, then you can do it manually initializing the translation component of the matrix:

```
Glfloat Tx = 1.0;
Glfloat Ty = 0.0;
Glfloat Tz = 0.0;

GLfloat trans[16] = {
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    Tx,  Ty,  Tz,  1.0
};
```

---

In C++ I recommend to use the [GLM library](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) for matrix and vector operations, which are related to OpenGL and GLSL.